# Font "Herr Von Muellerhoff Regular" gets cut off (Slider Revolution - Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, fonts, slider, webfonts, revolution-slider

In Google chrome, the slides with the font "Herr Von Muellerhoff Regular" gets cut off, and ive no idea why. 
I hve no real experience with Fonts but i think the font is the problem.

Can anyone confirm that the geometricts of this font arent correct ?

the first is the slide,
the second is the highlightet text on google fonts,
the thirs shows the cursor

after this "test" my thought was that the font isnt correct.
Any ideas ?

see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the css property `padding-right:12px;` to the involved elements should solve your problem.
If you have the same problem on the bottom with the letters y,q,p,g,j,.. you can do the same with `padding-bottom`

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Damn why i dont thought on that padding :X havent thougt on that because the bottom and top was fine ...

Comment: This Css fixed it for every letter in chrome !`#slide-padding {
    padding-right: 45px !important;
}`